# SPFX List View Command Set Extension

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions, command-set

Appreciate the good work in helping the SPFx community.

We have an issue with a custom ListView command set extension.

We are trying to implement an Export to Excel action for selected list items in a list view. When the list items were selected, we get access to the `event.selectedrows` by default. But we don't actually know what list this is, or what are the columns in this view. I have searched everywhere but no help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Your `CommandSet` inherits from `BaseListViewCommandSet` which contains a `context` of type `ListViewCommandSetContext`.

The `ListViewCommandSetContext` which contains `listview` which should give you information about the view, but doesn't seem for give any info.

The `ListViewCommandSetContext` inherits from `BaseComponentContext` (through `ExtensionContext`) which gives you `pageContext` of type `PageContext` which gives you your `list` as a `SPList`.

So you can access list information like this: `this.context.pageContext.list.serverRelativeUrl`

Comment: Thank you. But the this.pagecontext.listViews returns 0 columns.